# Clicking div does not change the width and height

Tags: javascript, css, onclick

I made a clicking div. After clicking the div (`some_id1`, some`enter code here`_id2), you need to change the value on each div (`width`, `height`, `background-color`).
Background-color works normally, but width and height are not working. I cannot find out where I made a mistake.

```js
var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
var divCount = div.length;
var clickedDivId

for (var i = 0; i < divCount; i += 1) {
    div[i].onclick = function(e) {
        clickedDivId = this.id
    };
}

function ColorChange(){
  if(clickedDivId == "some_id1"){
     var x = document.getElementById("divbackgroundcolor").value;
        document.getElementById(clickedDivId).style.backgroundColor = x;
  }
  if(clickedDivId == "some_id2"){
     var y = document.getElementById("divbackgroundcolor").value;
        document.getElementById(clickedDivId).style.backgroundColor = y;
  }
}

function ChengeWidth(){
  if(clickedDivId == "some_id1"){
  var z = document.getElementById("divwidth").value;
        document.getElementById(clickedDivId).style.width = z;
  }
  if(clickedDivId == "some_id2"){
     var w = document.getElementById("divwidth").value;
        document.getElementById(clickedDivId).style.width = w;
  }
}
```

```css
#some_id1{
  width: 50px;
height: 50px;
margin: 10px;
background-color: red;
}

#some_id2{
  width: 50px;
height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<select id="divwidth" onchange="ChengeWidth()">
     <option value="100px">100px</option>
</select>

<input type="color" id="divbackgroundcolor" onchange="ColorChange()">

<div class="some_style" id="some_id1"></div>
<div class="some_style" id="some_id2"></div>
```

Comment: Did you try using your browser's debugging tool?

Comment: Perhaps `onclick` rather than `onchange` (You should really be adding event handlers in JavaScript, rather that through inline HTML5 attributes to preserve separation of content)

Comment: Since your menu only has one option you can never change the value, so `onchange` never runs.

Comment: Also you saving clickedDivId value so you don't need use if() checks, just run var w = document.getElementById("divwidth").value;
    document.getElementById(clickedDivId).style.width = w;

Comment: I want to give a little piece of advice since I see this a lot on stack overflow: make your problem as small as possible. In this particular case: does the method work if you call it directly (hardcode a clickedDivId value). If so move on to the next step: does a change in <option> work (so .. add more options to test) and so on. It makes developing so much more easy since you can focus on one single task.

Comment: In your select you have only one option, so your onchange never runs because there is no other option to choose and to trigger the onchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
var divCount = div.length;
var clickedDivId

for (var i = 0; i < divCount; i += 1) {
    div[i].onclick = function(e) {
        clickedDivId = this.id
    };
}

function ColorChange(){
  if(clickedDivId == "some_id1"){
     var x = document.getElementById("divbackgroundcolor").value;
        document.getElementById(clickedDivId).style.backgroundColor = x;
  }
  if(clickedDivId == "some_id2"){
     var y = document.getElementById("divbackgroundcolor").value;
        document.getElementById(clickedDivId).style.backgroundColor = y;
  }
}

function ChengeWidth(){
  if(clickedDivId == "some_id1"){
  var z = document.getElementById("divwidth").value;
        document.getElementById(clickedDivId).style.width = z;
  }
  if(clickedDivId == "some_id2"){
     var w = document.getElementById("divwidth").value;
        document.getElementById(clickedDivId).style.width = w;
  }
}
```

```css
#some_id1{
  width: 50px;
height: 50px;
margin: 10px;
background-color: red;
}

#some_id2{
  width: 50px;
height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">

</head>
<body>
<select id="divwidth" onchange="ChengeWidth()">
     <option value="100px">100px</option>
      <option value="200px">200px</option>
       <option value="300px">300px</option>
       <option value="50px">50px</option>
</select>

<input type="color" id="divbackgroundcolor" onchange="ColorChange()">

<div class="some_style" id="some_id1"></div>
<div class="some_style" id="some_id2"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The mistake was you have only one option in the drop down.

Answer (score 0):

The menu only has one option, so you can't change the value and the `onchange` event never triggers. If you give it multiple options, the code works.

```js
var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
var divCount = div.length;
var clickedDivId

for (var i = 0; i < divCount; i += 1) {
  div[i].onclick = function(e) {
    clickedDivId = this.id
  };
}

function ColorChange() {
  if (clickedDivId == "some_id1") {
    var x = document.getElementById("divbackgroundcolor").value;
    document.getElementById(clickedDivId).style.backgroundColor = x;
  }
  if (clickedDivId == "some_id2") {
    var y = document.getElementById("divbackgroundcolor").value;
    document.getElementById(clickedDivId).style.backgroundColor = y;
  }
}

function ChengeWidth() {
  if (clickedDivId == "some_id1") {
    var z = document.getElementById("divwidth").value;
    document.getElementById(clickedDivId).style.width = z;
  }
  if (clickedDivId == "some_id2") {
    var w = document.getElementById("divwidth").value;
    document.getElementById(clickedDivId).style.width = w;
  }
}
```

```css
#some_id1 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}

#some_id2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<select id="divwidth" onchange="ChengeWidth()">
  <option value="50px">50px</option>
  <option value="100px">100px</option>
  <option value="150px">150px</option>
  <option value="200px">200px</option>
</select>

<input type="color" id="divbackgroundcolor" onchange="ColorChange()">

<div class="some_style" id="some_id1"></div>
<div class="some_style" id="some_id2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div id="some_id1" class="clickable"></div>
<div id="some_id2" class="clickable"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.clickable {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;  
}
```

**Javascript**

```
let current;

function changeColor() {
  const color = document.getElementById("divbackgroundcolor").value;
  current.style.backgroundColor = color;
}

function changeWidth() {
  const width = document.getElementById("divwidth").value;
  current.style.width = width;
}

function initialize() {
    const clickable = document.querySelectorAll('.clickable');

    clickable.forEach((item) => {
    item.onClick = () => {
      current = this;
      changeColor();
      changeWidth();
    }
  });
}

initialize();
```

My approach would be to split the problem in small chunks as you can see in my javascript proposal. Basically each method is a step which can be fully tested before moving on to the next portion:

- Add event handlers to elements (I changed it to a class, rather than applying it to all `<div>`-elements). Use `console.log` to make sure everything works as expected.
- Change the color; first call it immediately without the click handling in between. Does it work? Probably not because I did not include `#divwidth` in my example, but hopefully you see the approach I'm aiming for.
- Next change the width; same as previous: I did not include `#divbackgroundcolor` so it won't work yet
- Finally tie everything together and call the methods within the click handler

Hopefully I've pointed you in the right direction; good luck!